# How to send an amount directly from a stripe account to a debit card?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to send an amount directly to a debit card from a stripe account. Using /v1/transfers with destination: card_xxxxxxxx, gives `No such destination`. What am I doing wrong? Is there a different api method for doing this?

Comment: You should reach out to Support and explain to them what you're trying to do to confirm that your use case is supported; they can provide you guidance from there: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, unfortunately.

To send a money FROM Stripe account to someone, you'll need to create a `Connect` account. And then you can send the money to that account via Stripe.

You cannot simply send money to a card from a Stripe account.

You have to create a Connected account from Stripe, and then you have to send money to that account. And then the user can `Payout` to his/her bank from his/her connected account.